# Can anyone use Tumble or Overrun as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

The book reads, “Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take an additional action on your turn called a bonus action. This isn’t a feature, spell, or other ability, it is an action."

So, does this mean I can’t use it as a bonus action unless I have a Feature, Spell, or Other Ability that grants it? Or should they be counted as "Other Abilities" and anyone can use them as a bonus action if they want to? The DMG just said Action or Bonus Action; are these convertible in either direction?

Comment: I've edited that answer to clarify and emphasise the answer to the point you added. It already answered it, but making it extra-clear is helpful, thanks.